# Pandas: How can I change for all the columns the middle names to first letters and keep the first and last the same

Tags: python, pandas

Still learning pandas so please explain like I'm a newbie.
I'm trying to change all the rows of a column that have names for example this:
RECIPE BOX WITH METAL HEART

and I need to make a new string only with the first letters of the middle names and the first and the last name stay the same way.

Like this: RECIPE B W M HEART

I know how to do this, not changing the last name but changing the rest.
def name(s):
l = s.split()
new = ""
for i in range(len(l)-1):
s = l[i]
new += (s[0].upper()+'.')
new += l[-1].title()
return new
s ="Helena Blanca Fernandez"
print(name(s))

But I don't know how to do the way requested;

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex to match only the middle words:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(?<=\s)(\S)\S*(?=\s)', r'\1', regex=True)

# or
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace('(?<=\s\S)\S*(?=\s)', '', regex=True)
```

Example:

```
                           col                 new
0  RECIPE BOX WITH METAL HEART  RECIPE B W M HEART
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZK7qz/1)

Comment: You are very gooood